# Postman - Unable to send request body as JSON file in Formdata

Tags: json, postman, multipartform-data, content-type, request-headers

I am trying to create a PUT request in POSTMAN . I am passing request body formdata, where I browse and select a json file **"test.json"** which contains request in json format.

I have updated the Content-Type as **application/json**.

But it's throwing following error.

> **"Input string
>   '----------------------------919570725980811960289934' is not a valid
>   number. Path '', line 1, position 52."**

The content of the Json File is as follows

```
{
   "id":2,
   "ipAddress":"0.0.0.0",
   "port":50667,
   "status":0,
   "dataManagerSourceName":"aaab"
}
```

PFB the screenshots

[Request with headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbW72.png)

[Request Body form data section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mlf3V.png)

Comment: it could be caused due to the api and not necessaryly by postman itself. are you sure the api is been hit?? can you privide logs by the api??

Comment: Yes...API is been hit when I provided the same json file contents as raw json body.

Comment: can you tell us the postman logs , here is link to help you find them https://support.getpostman.com/hc/en-us/articles/360033270134-Where-can-I-find-logs-for-the-Postman-app-

Comment: btw when tranferring a file in postman , the body type should be binary here is link to help you https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/collection-runs/working-with-data-files/

Comment: To add on...I have provided the content as "Text" instead of "File" in "formdata" tab. There also I got the same error. "input string .......4463464363454u64386" is not a valid number. Path '' line1 etc

Comment: Can you provide the postman or api logs, it's difficult to help you with this information